# Why isn't spring boot's @Retryable being triggered when running unit test?

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, mockito

I created a basic set-up to try out Spring Retry, but it's not working for some reason. I think I have all of the annotations needed so I'm not sure what's wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

In AppConfig.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class AppConfig { 
   //run the spring application 
}
```

In SomeClass.java:

```
@Component
public class SomeClass{
   public SomeClass() { }

   int counter = 0;

   @Retryable(value = { SomeException.class }, maxAttempts = 3)
   public void someMethod(){
      counter++;
      System.out.println(counter);
      throw new SomeException("An exception was thrown!");
   }
}
```

In TestSomeClass.java:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes=AppConfig.class)
public class TestSomeClass {

    @Test
    public void test() {
       SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
       obj.someMethod();
    }

}
```

When I run the test the counter will only print '1' and the exception is thrown, so it's not being re-run as expected.

Comment: Inject the bean, don’t use your own object.

Comment: Same underlying reason as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null: Spring isn't managing your `SomeClass`, so it doesn't apply the advice.